# display html content to view using template in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am not able to display the html content to view format same html is coming in view page..

html part:

```
    <div class="container main-container" ui-view="main"></div>
```

controller part:

```
    .config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
      $stateProvider.state( 'admin', {
        url: '/admin',
        views: {
          "main": {
           controller: 'AdminCtrl',
           template: '{{adminContent}}'
          }      
        }
      });
    }).controller( 'AdminCtrl', function AboutCtrl($scope, GetNavTemplate) {
       $scope.adminContent = '<ul><li>abcd</li><li>abcd</li></ul>';
    });
```

but in view page it appears:

```
<ul><li>abcd</li><li>abcd</li></ul>
```

I need in view format..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-bind-html directive to bind HTML -

```
<li><a href="#" data-ng-bind-html="$scope.adminContent"></a></li>
```

Comment: @lort It works in angular 1.2 rc3? Are you thinking of ng-bind-html-unsafe?

Comment: but i have to display through templates ...  in templates I can assign variable through controller ...

Comment: my comment was @lort who was saying that it wasn't supported.  I don't understand what problem you have that the answer doesn't fix so if you get a chance give me a better explanation

Comment: whatever I am passing here  $scope.adminContent = '<ul><li>abcd</li><li>abcd</li></ul>'; full html content is displaying in view main, i need the html view but here the full code is displaying..

Answer (score 0):

If you use lower version of angular js, you can use
ng-bind-html-unsafe decretive like below.

`<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="adminContent"></div>`

If you are using latest versions this decretive is deprecated and you could implement your self the decretive.

See the fiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/nehanagaraju/zB8pK/ it is implemented here.